# Unable to share Bitmap Image and Html Content together?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, c#-5.0

I am creating an application where I am sharing a InkManager stroke by first saving the inkmanager stroke to local setting and then reading it as stream and sharing.

Now the HTML content is getting shared but there is no image attached to email. If I comment the code to share html the image is getting attached while sharing through email app. But both are not getting shared at once. How can I achieve this???

Code:

```
DataPackage requestData = request.Data;
                requestData.Properties.Title =        this.PageViewModel.JobInformationDetail.JobNumber;
                requestData.Properties.Description = this.PageViewModel.JobInformationDetail.CustomerSignatureName;
                //requestData.SetText("Sample Text");

                RandomAccessStreamReference signatureStream = await GetInkManagerStream();

                if (signatureStream != null)
                {
                    requestData.SetBitmap(signatureStream);
                }

                requestData.SetHtmlFormat(Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.HtmlFormatHelper.CreateHtmlFormat(this.GetMailDescription()));
```

Convert InkManager to stream

```
private async Task<RandomAccessStreamReference> GetInkManagerStream()
    {
        IRandomAccessStream signatureStream = null;

        StorageFile myMerge = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("sign.png", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        IOutputStream signature = await myMerge.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

        if (signature != null)
        {
            await _inkManager.SaveAsync(signature);
            signature.Dispose();
        }

        signatureStream = await myMerge.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
        RandomAccessStreamReference streamRef = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(signatureStream);
        signatureStream.Dispose();

        return streamRef;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by awaiting an `async` method inside your `DataRequested` event handler. If you're doing this, you need to use `DataRequestReferral`:

```
private async void OnDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    var deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral();

    // the rest of your method, including the awaiting call

    deferral.Complete();
}
```

By doing this you're telling the caller that it needs to wait for an async call to complete before continuing. At the end you signal it to continue by calling `deferral.Complete()`. Without it the caller continues before you actually set the bitmap, thus the error.

EDIT:

Windows 8 Mail app is not a share target for images shared like this, though. For the Mail app to be available you need to share the image as a storage item:

```
var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(@"sign.png");
var imageItems = new List<IStorageItem>();
imageItems.Add(file);
requestData.SetStorageItems(imageItems);
```

Now Mail will show up as one of available targets. When you're sharing images, it's best to use both `SetBitmap()` and `SetStorageItems()` to get more share targets available since not all apps support both data types.

EDIT 2:

Also the Mail app only picks up one type of shared content, either HTML or StorageItems (if no HTML is provided) as you've already noticed. The only workaround I know of, is to embed the images into the HTML content:

```
var resourceName = "logo.png";
var html = String.Format("<p>HTML content</p><img src='{0}'/>", resourceName);
requestData.ResourceMap[resourceName] = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(
    new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/sign.png"));
requestData.SetHtmlFormat(HtmlFormatHelper.CreateHtmlFormat(html));
```

You can read more about this approach in a [blog post by Mike Taulty](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2012/10/19/windows-store-apps-sharing-html-with-images.aspx).

Comment: I did this also on share page but the image is not getting attached.... its getting saved in Picture folder but not attached...

Comment: @BalrajSingh Where do you want to attach it to? Which share target do you have in mind?

Comment: Email I need to attach to and send it through that.

Comment: @BalrajSingh I added a snippet to my answer, for sharing an image so that the Mail app will pick it up.

Comment: @BalrajSingh I've just noticed that you made another edit to you original question (I suggest you post a new question in future instead, since such edits can get easily overlooked). I included another suggestion to my answer.

Comment: OK Damir. I will surely follow ur suggestion. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Hi guys, Is possible convert the stream to IStorageItem? see please my current code => https://gist.github.com/jdnichollsc/619f9db2c3e61667ea35

Comment: @JuanDavid You'd probably get more feedback if you created a new question on StackOverflow. I commented your Gist with a suggestion, though.

Comment: Thanks for your help!